# Git wrong commit parent

Tags: git, branch, parent

I was just commiting some changes I've done to a project on a branch and I discovered that git assigned the wrong parent to my commit.

As you can see: [image: HERE]

tig shows me that the highlighted commit(the one that was done on the  current branch TODAY with the message `redirect user after login`) comes from a merge done two days ago, which is wrong because if I checkout the `feature-loose-logging` branch I can't see that commit there.

So my commit should have been placed right after `added license` commit.

Why does git chose to assign a parent on the `feature-loose-logging` branch?

Comment: I think this is actually a perfectly reasonable question, not too localized - it does ask about a specific case, but it's effectively asking how `tig` orders commits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are wrong, tig doesn't show you that "the highlighted commit comes from a merge done two days ago". Please examine the graph more carefully.

Comment: Oh, shoot. I understand now. But still, WHY is it below the `added license` commit?

Comment: Probably because of topological sort.

Comment: @Paul: `tig` can't put two things on one line, so at some point it has to decide how to order things. You'll see the same sort of thing in `gitk`. It's trying to keep sequences of commits together. Note that the most recent commit on the right side is actually newer than the most recent one on the left side.